# Linux date translation to different time zone

Tags: bash, time, timezone, date

The Linux server is hosted in EST timezone. But I want to translate the output of date command to IST(Indian Standard time +5:30 hrs) format and use it in a shell script. Is there any option available for date command to do this or have manually add/subtract hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following command to get the date output in the timezone GMT+5:30.

```
$ TZ='Asia/Kolkata' date
```

You can choose whatever timezone you want from `tzselect`.